# How to pass a function taking an Eigen vector as an argument and returning an Eigen vector to another class/function

Tags: c++, c++14, eigen

For context, I'm trying to write a class that solves a system of nonlinear equations (a root finder). For this, my interface is as follows: the constructor takes takes a function that takes an Eigen vector and returns an Eigen vector (the system to solve), and stores it in `func`, and the `newt` member function takes an Eigen vector (the initial guess), runs the algorithm with that initial guess, and returns the Eigen vector `r` such that `func(r) = {0, 0, ..., 0}`.

Now I've written the class's functions as instructed [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html): writing template functions that take instantiations of `MatrixBase`. My questions is, how do I do something similar if I also want to pass a function to the class? The most obvious approach, which I tried, is to store a private `std::function` object and templatize it in a manner similar to what I did with the functions. It didn't work out, and I'm unsure how to proceed.

```
class Newt {
private:
    template<typename TR, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
    tuple<TR,bool> lnsrch(const MatrixBase<T1> &xold, const double fold, const MatrixBase<T2> &g, MatrixBase<T3> &p, const double stepmax);

    template <typename TR, typename T1, typename T2>
    TR fdjac(const MatrixBase<T1> &x, const MatrixBase<T2> &fvec);

    template <typename TR, typename T1>
    std::function<TR(MatrixBase<T1>)> func;

public:
    template <typename TR, typename T1>
    Newt(std::function<TR(MatrixBase<T1>)> f) : func(f) { };

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    tuple<T1,bool> newt(const MatrixBase<T2> &xx);
};
```

I get the following errors:

```
g++-6 -c -Wall -O2 -march=native -flto newt.cpp
In file included from newt.cpp:8:0:
newt.h:218:40: error: data member ‘func’ cannot be a member template
  std::function<TR(MatrixBase<T1>)> func;
                                        ^
newt.h: In constructor ‘Newt::Newt(std::function<TR(Eigen::MatrixBase<U>)>)’:
newt.h:222:46: error: class ‘Newt’ does not have any field named ‘func’
  Newt(std::function<TR(MatrixBase<T1>)> f) : func(f) { };
                                              ^~~~
make: *** [newt.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas? How can I do what I want? Any alternative ways of accomplishing what I'm trying to acomplish (write a class that runs the algorithm on an arbitrary given function "`Eigen_Vector f(Eigen_Vector x)`")?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store a reference to the function as a class member, then you have to pass the function type as a template parameter of your class, similar to what [Eigen::LevenbergMarquart](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/13ee053f74aff786af558e33873ae7cedbf45653/unsupported/Eigen/src/LevenbergMarquardt/LevenbergMarquardt.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#LevenbergMarquardt.h-101) does. For instance:

```
template<typename Func>
class Newt {
    const Func& func;
  public:
    Newt(const Func& f) : func(f) {}
};
```

You can then write a helper to figure out the functor type automatically like:

```
auto solver = make_newt(my_func);
```

where `my_func` can be whatever including lambdas.